# Missing WWW folder Cordova/PhoneGap iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

After downloading and installing Cordova/PhoneGap, I created a new xCode project.
After trying to follow the get started guide I cam to find that I have no 'www' folder to copy into xCode!

Am I going wrong somewhere?

[image: Screenshot 1]
<sub>(source: [jonweb.co.uk](http://jonweb.co.uk/phonegap/screenshot1.png))</sub>

[image: Screenshot 2]
<sub>(source: [jonweb.co.uk](http://jonweb.co.uk/phonegap/screenshot2.png))</sub>

Comment: did you run it as it is?? it will create the `/www` folder after running first time only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the app once, the www folder will be created in your directory. You then just need to drag it into XCode to tell your project about it

Comment: I didn't run it properly the first time. I didn't realise it creates it after the first build.

Answer (score 0):

did you [start](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) with 'Cordova-based Application'?

[image]